# How can I make Ubuntu server always install updates without asking?

Tags: ubuntu, automation, update

I would like to set some Ubuntu Server VM's to always pull updates (nightly) with out asking?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at *cron-apt*

Comment: +1.  Please use a tool already built for this.

Comment: nothing wrong with using a tool pre-made for these things, but when you're talking about installing a package vs. a 1 line cronjob, it gets a little bit of a toss up.

Comment: @cpbills: The suggested 1 line cronjob does a bad job when it comes to error reporting: You just get a daily mail by cron containing all the ouput. cron-apt is a bit better here.

Comment: @Florian Diesch what error output are you going to see? it's running in the background to update apt-get, and then download the packages (since he said he wanted to download only) and adding `2> /var/log/auto-apt 1> /dev/null` would log errors. heck, even `1> /dev/null` would only mail error messages. they are both solutions, depending on the person, one may be preferable to another, and for /me/ the single line cronjob would be preferable.

Comment: @cpbills: Of course your solution is fine but cron-apt has some more features that may very well worth installing an additional package. As for the messages I like to have errors and updates logged to syslog so they are in the right context, get archived and I get notified via my usual log checker

Comment: just to be pedantic, you could do `1>/dev/null | logger -t apt-cron-job` but yes, i understand `cron-apt` has more potentially useful features. for me, though, i wouldn't go beyond a single line cronjob for this.

Comment: For more info regarding installation and configuration of cron-apt check http://www.debianadmin.com/automatic-update-of-packages-using-cron-apt.html

Answer (score 2):

i wouldn't recommend unattended updates, but you can do something like this:

create a file... `update.sh` for example, throw it in `/usr/local/sbin/`

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update
apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

run `chmod 700 /usr/local/sbin/update.sh` and `chown root.root /usr/local/sbin/update.sh`

then in root's crontab, add a line:

```
15 03 * * * /usr/local/sbin/update.sh
```

this will kick off your `apt-get update` and `apt-get -y dist-upgrade` every night at 3:15am

or just:

```
15 03 * * * /usr/sbin/apt-get update && /usr/sbin/apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

in root's crontab `sudo crontab -e` to edit it.

if you want to download only:

```
15 03 * * * /usr/sbin/apt-get update && /usr/sbin/apt-get -yd dist-upgrade
```

Comment: the only reason i don't recommend automatic updates is that sometimes new packages clobber your old custom configurations.

Comment: I agree, but that can at least be mitigated to a certain extent by installing something like etckeeper which will keep your configuration files in git/bzr.  If they packagers do their job and follow the policies there isn't supposed to be any config breaking changes that happen during a single release.

Comment: ... local repository ...

Comment: sure, there is that, if you just want to download the updates... but you didn't ask that.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article [**here**](http://maketecheasier.com/remove-the-annoying-update-manager-pop-up-in-ubuntu-jaunty/2009/06/18) that will tell you how to disable the update pop-up.

You then need to run

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

from root's crontab